# Finding the upper limit of range for standard deviations

Tags: standard-deviation, range

A very basic question - from someone who last studied Maths 25 years ago and has forgotten more then he ever learnt!

I have a data set of weekly sales for products, and wish to determine what stock figure would be appropriate to fulfil say 95% of demand, given the historical sales behaviour of that product.  To make the concept simpler disregard factors such as product lead time.

My initial thought was to use Standard Deviation to look at the spread of sales results, and add 2 x Standard Deviation to the Mean to determine the 95% upper limit.  However, because the distribution of the sales figures is not the "Normal" bell shaped distribution, but tends to be left-skewed due to occasional low / out of stocks restricting sales, doing it this way leads to a figure that is often greater than the maximum sales value in the set.  So it's not this that I need to determine the upper limit of the 2* standard deviation range.

I'd do the calculation in Excel.  Any ideas, or would you approach this a different way entirely?

Comment: Maybe something as simple as 95-th percentile will work for you?

Comment: Are you looking for the 95% confidence interval for the mean of these stock figures, or are you looking for the range of values which covers 95% of your data?